# CSS apply background color to div on hover but only if link is hovered

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change background color of a div when the link within it is hovered..

```css
.link {
    padding:50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.link:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="link">
        <a href="example.com">This is the link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently it applys the hover as soon as I enter the `link` div. Is there a way to only apply the hover when I am over the text but still apply the background hover color to the whole div?

Answer (score 6):

Some pointer-events trick can do it

```css
.link {
  padding: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  pointer-events: none; /* disable on the div */
}

.link a {
  pointer-events: initial; /* re-enable for only the link */
}

.link:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="link">
    <a href="example.com">This is the link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice approach. I like it.

Comment: Nice, is there a way to have the hover stay applied to the whole div after the initial hover? So once you have hovered over the text link, you need to move out of the div to release the hover?

Comment: @jsmitter3 this is a complete new requirement. If this is what you want, you should make your question clear to get accurate answer. What I have done cannot achieve what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods to achieve this effect is by using javascript (with jquery for convinience)

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.link a', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}

$(document).on('mouseout', '.link a', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
}
```

Comment: The question did not mention Javascript.

Comment: The question asked how to apply background, but didn't mentioned "by using only css".

Comment: Hi, I was just looking at the tags.

Comment: I understand, but developing has many ways to reach the same result, so mine is an option.

Answer (score -1):

There is no parent selector in CSS. In order to do this, you've to use JavaScript. I have provided jQuery solution whenever you hover on the anchor, the div changes to red, and when you move out it will change to white.

```
$('.link a').on('mouseover',function(){
  $('.link').css('background-color','red');
});
$('.link a').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $('.link').css('background-color','white');
});
```

```css
.link {
    padding:50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
/*You can remove this :hover effect

.link:hover a {
    background:red;
}
 */
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="link">
        <a href="example.com">This is the link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why jQuery when you can solve it with pure CSS?!

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 I'd actually love to solve it with pure CSS. Can you please post a solution?

Comment: There‘s already one. Check the other answers

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 I've just checked it. It is a pretty creative approach actually. But it seems like the op wants other requirement,